# RSpec Stubbing Service Object Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having an issue with stubbing out a call to a service object (QuickbooksService) from an AR object. As far as I can tell the method should be stubbed properly and return the value I'm specifying but when I run the spec I can see the method being called and failing.

Here's the class definition of the object I'm testing.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_invoice
    QuickbooksService.new(:estimate).create_invoice(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  end
end
```

And from order_spec

```
describe("#create_invoice") do
  expect(QuickbooksService.new(:estimate)).to receive(:create_invoice).and_return(1)
end
```

I've also tried

```
allow(QuickbooksService.new(:estimate)).to receive(:form_invoice_create).with(anything()).and_return(1)
```

So instead of returning `1` the `create_invoice` method is being executed inside of QuickbooksService. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are stubbing a seperate instance. i.e When you define the expectation, you telling it to expect that a particular instance receives a call to the method, but when the code is executed, it is creating a different instance. What you need to do is allow any instance to receive the method call. Something like `allow_any_instance_of(QuickbooksService).to receive(:invoice_create)` will work, but it is much better practice to create a double, something like:

```
let(:quickbooks_service) { instance_double(QuickbooksService) }

describe("#create_invoice") do
  before { allow(quickbooks_service).to receive(:create_invoice).and_return(1) }

  it "Creates quickbook invoice" do
    order.create_invoice
    expect(quickbooks_service).to have_received(:create_invoice)
  end
end
```

See: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

Comment: thanks so much! I was looking at the `instance_double` docs but didn't put it together as you have. cheers. i would vote up but i lack the rep.. 8(

Comment: Is it possible to declare an instance_double with arguments? This specific implementation of my QuickbooksService object requires the argument `:estimate` and without it the stub doesn't work. I don't see anywhere in the docs that refer to this possibility.

Comment: Of course! you can match the arguments using `.with(...)` e.g `before { allow(quickbooks_service).to receive(:create_invoice).with(arg1, arg2, arg3).and_return(1) }` https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the declaration of the instance_double. I would like to instantiate it like `instance_double(QuickbooksService.new(:estimate))` but RSpec doesn't like that.

Comment: Exactly, that is incorrect implementation. An `instance_double` takes a class name or
  object as its first argument, then verifies that any methods being stubbed would be present on an _instance_ of that class. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/example_methods.rb#L56

Comment: `allow_any_instance_of` [is deprecated](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance) and should be replaced by `allow`. [Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/basics/allowing-messages) are some examples

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are instantiating the class while stubbing it `allow(QuickbooksService.new(:estimate)).to receive(:form_invoice_create).with(anything()).and_return(1)`

Try this:

```
allow_any_instance_of(QuickbooksService).to receive(:form_invoice_create).with(anything()).and_return(1)
```